# Why Google Map is not displaying on Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I have everything installed and prepared in order to run a google map on android Genymotion Emulator. But for some reasons it doesn't get displayed. I understand that the program is able to navigate to that Map layout page, but the actual map doesn't appear there.

Looks like this:

[image]

I have tried with different Emulator, but they are the same.

What's wrong with this?

This is emulator specification:

[image]

fragment_map_detailed.XML:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapDemoActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.lab3_fragment_list" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.mycompany.lab3_fragment_list.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />"

    <uses-permission android:name="com.mycompany.lab3_fragment_list.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ItemListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ItemDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_item_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".ItemListActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ItemListActivity" />
        </activity>



        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBDAQyMry1pdb9aCEvzBR0eTO79vj0MtU4" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ItemDetailFragment:

```
.....................
...................
     else if (mItem.id.equals("4")) {

                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_detailed, container, false);


                }
.....................
....................
```

[NOTE: This issue refers a part of my app. My App is big, I have used list-item view & dummyContent. For activity I have used master-overflow.]

Comment: You might not want to display your real mapkey here for own security reasons.

Comment: Have you tried on a real device?

Comment: It's been like that ever since they don't really support OpenGL ES 2 too well, if i remember correctly.

Comment: A Honey Bustard, good point! But I made change in it.

Comment: A Honey Bustard, I have't tried. should I?

Comment: Yes, when it works in ar real device, then you at least know it has to be a problem with the emulator and not with your app.

Answer (score -1):

I think your google playbservices are not installed in emulator.

Comment: Please note that is against the licensing terms and conditions to install Google Play Services on Genymotion.

Comment: Kavis, it's installed. I download that corresponding Zip file and drag and dropped it.

Answer (score -1):

Download google play services from [here](https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145) or [here](http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/). Then drag and drop the file to your emulator and you are ready to go.

Comment: Please note that is against the licensing terms and conditions to install Google Play Services on Genymotion.

Comment: Simon, does it mean that I can never use it in Genymotion emulator